# Open Graph meta tags not accessible, preview of page in Facebook shows "422"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, meta-tags

I can't make my open graph tags accessible to Facebook. When I try to share a page, the site links properly, but the og attributes don't show up, and the title just displays as "422". I'm not sure what this means.

When I run the facebook debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ I get the following error, which isn't very helpful:

```
Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.
```

Using the echo feature in the debug tools, all I get is:

```
Document returned no data
```

The meta tags appear to be set up properly in my document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="robots" content="noarchive,noodp,noydir" />
  <meta name="referrer" content="always" />
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="375576830972731" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Site Name" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Title of content" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://website.domain.com/123456" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/domain/media/images/001/original/001" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Description of content" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
</head>
```

I made sure to allow for the Facebook crawlers in `robots.txt`:

```
User-agent: Facebot
Allow: /

User-agent: facebookexternalhit/1.1
Allow: /
```

What I am I missing?

Comment: What is the url you are trying to share?

Comment: The first time I loaded that it took forever. And the debug page also say timeout

Comment: It loads right away for me?

Comment: After the first time yes

Comment: I just tried on a completely different machine, and it loads right away. Anyway, I'm pretty sure "timeout" isn't the reason its failing.

Comment: Not it doesn't say timeout. Now it say your website don't return any data

Comment: Ok, so, how do you suggest I get it to return data?

Comment: Debug the request that Facebook is doing to your server

Comment: That's where I'm having trouble. Nothing shows up in the Heroku logs  and if I run `curl "http://mysiteurl"`, the head content shows `<title>422</title>`. The issue appears related to this [question]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572571/facebook-debugger-wont-scrape-my-site), however, the question was never fully answered in the accepted answer.

Comment: Sharing the actual URL you're trying to debug would be really useful, since we can't actually reproduce your issue nor have any idea what the FB debugger finds as an error when you try to scrape it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was my `protect_from_forgery`method in `application.rb`. I added an exception and the Facebot can now see the page.

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController    
  protect_from_forgery except: :show
```